# Как установить состояние классового компонента React во время его вызова?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть класс кнопки:

```
class Button extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: ''
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    clickEvent() {}

    handleClick() {
        this.clickEvent();
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <button class="simple-button" onClick={this.handleClick}>
            {this.state.text}
        </button>
        );
    }
}
```

И класс другой кнопки, который наследуется от первого.

```
class NumberButton extends Button {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: '',
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    clickEvent() {
        
    }
}
```

Как установить состояние классового компонента NumberButton во время его вызова? Что-то вроде:

```
<NumberButton text="1"/>
```

Comment: использовать `props`

Comment: @Grundy Можно конкретнее?

Comment: `text: props.text`

Comment: @EzioMercer в смысле поменять state на props?

Comment: Где я такое сказал?

Comment: @EzioMercer А что тогда надо сделать?

Comment: Я же [написал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1435747/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-react-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0?noredirect=1#comment2560977_1435747), что надо сделать. Я вам прям строчку прописал вместо вас

Comment: @EzioMercer И куда надо эту строчку вставить?

Comment: Там где у вас `text: `

Comment: справка: [Components and Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)